# Cannot find module is looking in a wrong directory

Tags: node.js, npm

I've installed `nodemon` using `npm i -g nodemon` and this was installed in the global path which is:

> C:\Users\John\AppData\Roaming

so I started a new project using `npm i -y` and created a simple `index.js` entry point using:

```
{
  "name": "scp",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "start": "node index.js"
  },
  "keywords": [],
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "dependencies": {
    "express": "^4.17.1",
    "jsonwebtoken": "^8.5.1"
  }
}
```

when I start the app using `nodemon` I got:

> Error: Cannot find module 'C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\nodemon\bin\nodemon.js'

as you can see the path is actually wrong, so I tried to change it using:

```
npm config set prefix C:\Users\John\AppData\Roaming
npm config get prefix
```

and this return:

> C:\Users\John\AppData\Roaming

the problem's that when I start the app using `nodemon` I get the same error message 'cause the path is always wrong:

> Error: Cannot find module 'C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\nodemon\bin\nodemon.js'

how can I fix this?

Comment: You said you started a new project using 'npm i -y'. I can't find anything about the y flag on npm-install command documentation.

Comment: @lafleur It should be 'npm init -y' to create node module. -y is used for skipping all questions . https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/init

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Can you try to install nodemon in your current package.json using :

```
npm i --save nodemon
```

Then change your start script to

```
"start": "nodemon index.js"
```

Hope it works for you

Comment: Using the installation as dependency works but I would like to have `nodemon` separated and fix the main problem for the global packages

Comment: Use `nodemon index.js` to run the program

Comment: same problem .. .

Comment: I have just tried it on my side and it is working perfectly

Answer (score 2):

Another issue that causes a similar error is using "&" anywhere in the path name. npm will install packages in the correct location ('foobar&foobar/myApp/node_modules' folder) but the path to some package files will be wrong. The fix is to rename the folder that has "&" (foobar&foobar --> foobarAndfoobar) and run the following where your node_modules packages are installed:

```
rm -rf node_modules
npm install
```

I hope this saves a headache for anyone who ran into my issue.

Answer (score 0):

You can always put `nodemon` as dev dependency and specify it in the scripts section of your `package.json`. You don't need to install it globally when you need it.

Ex. (package.json)

```
 "scripts": {
    "start": "nodemon index.js"
  },
```

About your original problem...
It has to be something with the configuration of your npm/node. I would suggest to use something like NVM that handles multiple npm/node instances and configurations locally. It's something I would always suggest to use to any developer who uses node.

Take a look at it https://github.com/coreybutler/nvm-windows
And try with a local version of npm to understand where the problem comes from.
Be aware that your current (global) node installation might be in conflict with the NVM one (bin Paths... etc etc) so you might need to use only npm/nodes that come from NVM and get rid of the global one.

Answer (score 0):

Double-check if any of your directories has "&". Rename it and nodemon will work.. Broke my head for 1.5hrs.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).